# JUnit and Mockito: getToken() returns null despite configuring the mock to return a specific value

Tags: java, junit5

'm writing unit tests in Java using JUnit and Mockito. In my test case, I am attempting to mock the behavior of the autentication() method of the AutenticacionProxy class to return an AutenticarSesionResponse object with a fake token.

My problem is that, despite configuring the mock object to return a specific value for the getToken() method, it's returning null during the test execution.

I've tried using MockedConstruction to control the creation of new instances of the AutenticacionProxy class, but it still returns null.

este es mi test

// ... (imports)

```
@DisplayName("Prueba de Autenticación exitosa")
@Test
public void prueba() throws Exception {
    try (
            MockedConstruction<AutenticacionProxy> mock = Mockito.mockConstruction(AutenticacionProxy.class,
                    (mockInstance, context) -> {
                        AutenticarSesionResponse mockResponse = mock(AutenticarSesionResponse.class);
                        when(mockResponse.getToken()).thenReturn("tokenFalso");
                        when(mockInstance.autentication(anyString(), isNull(), anyString())).thenReturn(mockResponse);
                    });
            // ... (otros mocks)
    ) {
        // Llamada al método que estás probando
        DashBoardVD result = dashBoardVDService.autenticacion(dashBoardVD, requestContext);

        AutenticacionProxy proxy = new AutenticacionProxy();
        AutenticarSesionResponse response = proxy.autentication("algúnValorDeCIS", null, "algúnToken");
        assertNotNull(response);
        assertEquals("tokenFalso", response.getToken());
    }
}
```

este es el codigo de java

```
private DashBoardVD getPrueba(DashBoardVD dashBoardVD) throws VentaDigitalException {

        //1. Autenticar contra el banco
        AutenticarSesionResponse autenticarSesionResponse = new AutenticacionProxy().autentication(cis, null, token);
        //Asignar nuevo token
        token = autenticarSesionResponse.getToken();

//codigo
}
```

I'm writing unit tests in Java using JUnit and Mockito. In my test case, I'm trying to mock the behavior of the autentication() method from the AutenticacionProxy class to return an AutenticarSesionResponse object with a fake token.

```
@DisplayName("Successful Authentication Test")
@Test
public void prueba() throws Exception {
    try (
            MockedConstruction<AutenticacionProxy> mock  = Mockito.mockConstruction(AutenticacionProxy.class,
                    (mock, context) -> {
                        AutenticarSesionResponse mockResponse = mock(AutenticarSesionResponse.class);
                        when(mock.autentication(anyString(), isNull(), anyString())).thenReturn(mockResponse);
                        when(mockResponse.getToken()).thenReturn("tokenFalso");
                    });
            // Additional mock setup...
    ) {
        // Test logic...
        assertNotNull(response);  
     
    }
}
```